# tune SVM short data frame

Tags: r, svm

I am trying to build a classification model with this data frame:

```
str(aa)
'data.frame':   49 obs. of  967 variables:
 $ Lunes                                              : num  0.1 0.14 0.19 0.15 0.14 0.12 0.19 0.15 0.15 0.15 ...
 $ Martes                                             : num  0.15 0.16 0.21 0.17 0.15 0.14 0.2 0.13 0.16 0.15 ...
 $ Miercoles                                          : num  0.15 0.16 0.17 0.17 0.16 0.16 0.17 0.13 0.16 0.14 ...
 $ Jueves                                             : num  0.15 0.13 0.12 0.13 0.12 0.13 0.14 0.09 0.13 0.13 ...
 $ Viernes                                            : num  0.2 0.13 0.16 0.13 0.13 0.13 0.14 0.13 0.16 0.12 ...
 $ Sabado                                             : num  0.13 0.15 0.1 0.13 0.16 0.17 0.1 0.16 0.13 0.18 ...
 $ Domingo                                            : num  0.12 0.12 0.05 0.12 0.14 0.15 0.05 NA 0.11 0.13 ...
 $ CODNUEVZON                                         : int  7001 35801 24402 NA 17203 37102 24403 38402 60201 10404 ...
 $ POBLA                                              : int  363 4282 2090 NA 1477 32797 1694 17440 0 11045 ...
 $ BANCO.BOLIVARIANO                                  : int  1 1 1 NA 1 1 2 0 1 1 ...
 $ BANCO.DE.LOJA                                      : int  0 0 0 NA 1 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ BANCO.DELBANK                                      : int  0 0 0 NA 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ BANCO.DESARROLLO                                   : int  0 0 0 NA 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ BANCO.GUAYAQUIL                                    : int  0 3 0 NA 3 1 1 4 2 1 ...
 $ BANCO.INTERNACIONAL                                : int  0 4 1 NA 1 1 8 0 0 1 ...
 $ BANCO.PICHINCHA                                    : int  0 8 5 NA 14 1 4 13 7 0 ...
 $ BANCO.PROCREDIT                                    : int  0 0 0 NA 3 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ BANCO.PRODUBANCO                                   : int  0 6 0 NA 6 1 1 2 0 0 ...
 $ BANCO.SOLIDARIO                                    : int  0 1 0 NA 2 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ BANRED                                             : int  0 0 0 NA 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ COOP..29.DE.OCTUBRE                                : int  0 1 0 NA 1 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ COOP..ALIANZA.DEL.VALLE                            : int  0 0 1 NA 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ COOP..AMBATO                                       : int  0 0 0 NA 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ COOP..J.E.P                                        : int  0 0 0 NA 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ COOP..OSCUS                                        : int  0 0 0 NA 1 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ COOP..POLICIA.NACIONAL                             : int  0 0 0 NA 1 0 1 0 0 0 ...
 $ MUTUALISTA.PICHINCHA                               : int  0 1 0 NA 2 0 1 0 1 0 ...
 $ RED.TRANSACCIONAL.COONECTA                         : int  1 1 0 NA 0 0 1 1 0 0 ...
 $ TotalATM                                           : int  2 26 8 NA 36 5 19 20 11 3 ...
 $ Tiendas                                            : int  18 14 17 NA 9 88 18 58 41 48 ...
 $ advertising                                        : int  0 0 0 NA 0 0 0 0 1 0 ...
 $ animal_boarding                                    : int  0 0 0 NA 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ arts_centre                                        : int  0 0 0 NA 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ atm                                                : int  0 0 2 NA 0 3 6 3 0 0 ...
 $ bank                                               : int  0 11 2 NA 1 0 8 7 4 0 ...
 $ bar                                                : int  2 0 1 NA 0 1 1 0 0 5 ...
 $ bbq                                                : int  0 0 0 NA 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ bench                                              : int  0 0 0 NA 1 0 1 0 0 0 ...
 $ bicycle_parking                                    : int  0 0 0 NA 0 0 3 0 0 0 ...
 $ bicycle_rental                                     : int  0 0 0 NA 0 0 1 0 0 0 ...
 $ bicycle_repair_station                             : int  0 0 0 NA 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ biergarten                                         : int  0 0 0 NA 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ bureau_de_change                                   : int  0 0 0 NA 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ bus_station                                        : int  0 0 0 NA 0 0 2 0 0 0 ...
 $ cafe                                               : int  2 7 2 NA 0 4 11 0 8 1 ...
 $ cafe.ice_cream                                     : int  0 0 0 NA 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ car_rental                                         : int  0 0 0 NA 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ car_wash                                           : int  0 1 0 NA 0 0 1 0 1 0 ...
 $ charging_station                                   : int  0 0 0 NA 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ childcare                                          : int  0 0 0 NA 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ cinema                                             : int  0 1 0 NA 1 0 0 0 3 0 ...
 $ clinic                                             : int  2 0 0 NA 0 0 1 0 2 3 ...
 $ college                                            : int  0 0 1 NA 0 0 4 0 0 0 ...
 $ community_centre                                   : int  1 0 0 NA 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ computer                                           : int  0 0 0 NA 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ courthouse                                         : int  0 0 0 NA 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ coworking_space                                    : int  0 0 1 NA 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ dancing_school                                     : int  0 0 1 NA 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ dentist                                            : int  1 2 2 NA 0 7 0 4 2 5 ...
 $ doctors                                            : int  2 1 1 NA 1 1 0 1 0 0 ...
 $ dojo                                               : int  0 0 0 NA 0 0 0 0 1 1 ...
 $ drinking_water                                     : int  1 0 0 NA 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ driving_school                                     : int  0 0 0 NA 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ embassy                                            : int  0 0 1 NA 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ fast_food                                          : int  4 0 3 NA 1 1 1 0 4 8 ...
 $ fire_station                                       : int  0 0 0 NA 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ food_court                                         : int  0 0 0 NA 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ fountain                                           : int  0 0 0 NA 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ fuel                                               : int  0 0 0 NA 0 0 0 0 2 0 ...
 $ grave_yard                                         : int  0 0 0 NA 0 0 0 0 1 0 ...
 $ hospital                                           : int  0 0 0 NA 2 1 0 2 0 0 ...
 $ hunting_stand                                      : int  0 0 0 NA 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ ice_cream                                          : int  0 0 0 NA 0 0 0 0 1 0 ...
 $ internet                                           : int  0 0 0 NA 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ internet_cafe                                      : int  1 0 0 NA 0 3 1 1 0 0 ...
 $ kindergarten                                       : int  0 0 0 NA 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ language_school                                    : int  0 0 0 NA 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ library                                            : int  0 0 0 NA 0 0 1 0 1 0 ...
 $ marketplace                                        : int  0 0 0 NA 0 0 0 1 0 0 ...
 $ money_transfer                                     : int  0 0 0 NA 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ music_school                                       : int  0 0 0 NA 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ nightclub                                          : int  0 0 1 NA 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ parking                                            : int  0 0 1 NA 0 0 2 0 7 2 ...
 $ parking_entrance                                   : int  0 4 0 NA 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ parking_space                                      : int  0 0 0 NA 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ pharmacy                                           : int  3 3 1 NA 1 4 5 5 4 5 ...
 $ place_of_worship                                   : int  1 0 0 NA 0 1 0 3 1 0 ...
 $ police                                             : int  0 0 0 NA 0 0 1 0 0 0 ...
 $ post_box                                           : int  0 0 0 NA 0 0 0 0 1 0 ...
 $ post_office                                        : int  0 1 0 NA 0 0 0 1 0 1 ...
 $ pub                                                : int  0 0 0 NA 0 0 2 0 0 0 ...
 $ public_building                                    : int  0 0 0 NA 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ recycling                                          : int  0 0 0 NA 1 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ residence                                          : int  0 0 0 NA 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ restaurant                                         : int  2 9 5 NA 3 21 10 15 7 13 ...
 $ school                                             : int  0 1 3 NA 0 0 1 4 1 6 ...
 $ shelter                                            : int  1 0 0 NA 1 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ shower                                             : int  0 0 0 NA 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ showers                                            : int  0 0 0 NA 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  [list output truncated]
```

I am running a crossvalidated SVM model with tune function:

```
svm_tune <- tune(svm, catrent ~., data = aa, list(gamma = 2^(-1:1), cost = 2^(2:4)))
```

I am getting this error:

> Error in if (any(co)) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Comment: You need to do na.omit or replace the nan with some values ....However I would suggested you might wanna run a PCA or reduce dimension before running your SVM

Comment: Thank you! Know I am geeting this error: ‘cross’ must not exceed sampling size!, how can adjust the sampling size?

Comment: Have you scale your data ?

Comment: Add this line tc <- tune.control(cross = 10), and then svm_tune <- tune.svm(catrent~., data = aa, list(gamma= 2^(-1:1), cost = 2 ^(2:4)), tunecontrole=tc)

Comment: See my answer bellow and tell me if it helps !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following my comments here what I suggest.

Your error is due to presence of NA into your data. You can use different approach to take care of those but since you have only 49 observations I would not omit the na... I would take the mean of each column:

```
for(i in 1:ncol(aa)){
  aa[is.na(aa[,i]), i] <- mean(aa[,i], na.rm = TRUE)
}
```

Since you are using tune function. The data don't need to be scale before apply the function since it is done while running the function.

However, since you have only 49 observation you need to tune the cross argument in the tune fonction (have a look at the e1071 package details [e10171](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/e1071/e1071.pdf)).

```
tc <- tune.control(cross = 5)
model_1 <- tune.svm(catrent~., data =aa , list(gamma=2^(-1:1), cost = 2^(2:4)), tunecontrol = tc)
```

Should work!

Comment: After the for loop, I am getting this error - Error in data[, i] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Comment: Have you use = instead of <-?

Comment: Sorry i wrote data instead of aa jaha ,should work now

Comment: I don't understand your sentence "_I would woudl the mean of each column_". You might want to [edit] it.

Comment: Sorry wrote this too fast, fixed !